# List all my liked YouTube videos with the Apps Script Advanced YouTube Service

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

I'm trying to get a list of YouTube videos that I liked.  They aren't owned by me, so I can't search for videos owned by me.

The curl info from the "Try this API" is:

```
curl \
  'h_ttps://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics
     &myRating=like&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

I'm using the Advanced Service so I don't think that I need to include my API key, as that is built-in to the request.

What I've tried:

```
function getMyLikedVideos() {
  var results;

  results = YouTube.Search.list('snippet', {myRating: 'like', maxResults: 1});
 
  Logger.log('results: ' + results);

}
```

It runs without an error, but it returns a video that I definitely did not "like."

Result:

```
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1000000,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "etag": "99999999999999999",
    "items": [
        {
            "snippet": {
                "description": "abcde",
                "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
                "publishTime": "2021-03-27T02:57:44Z",
                "thumbnails": {
                    "default": {
                        "height": 90,
                        "url": "https://",
                        "width": 120
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "url": "https:",
                        "height": 360,
                        "width": 480
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "height": 180,
                        "url": "h",
                        "width": 320
                    }
                },
                "publishedAt": "2021-03-27T02:57:44Z",
                "channelTitle": "99999",
                "title": "title here",
                "channelId": "some ID"
            },
            "etag": "abcde",
            "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
            "id": {
                "videoId": "999999",
                "kind": "youtube#video"
            }
        }
    ],
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
    "regionCode": "ZZ",
    "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA"
}
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code: use `YouTube.Videos.list` instead of `YouTube.Search.list`.

Comment: Thanks.  That was definitely the issue.  It's not a typo though.  A typo would have been if I'd typed something like `Vedios` or `Vekios` or `Vidios`.  I used the entirely wrong sub class.  I wanted to search for something, so I though that using `Search` would work.

Comment: Your `curl` command calls correctly for the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint (modulo its URL starting with `h_ttps`!). That's why I deemed your issue to be a typo.

Comment: This is the first time that I've use the YouTube API.  So, it's easy to overlook the obvious.  You did provide the answer, so you should add a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function I'm using to get my liked videos.

```
function getMyLikedVideos(maxNmbrToGet,dataToGet) {
  var results;

  maxNmbrToGet = maxNmbrToGet ? maxNmbrToGet : 10;
  dataToGet = dataToGet ? dataToGet : "id";

  //YouTube.Videos.list.list()
  results = YouTube.Videos.list(dataToGet, {myRating: 'like', maxResults: maxNmbrToGet});

  //Logger.log('results: ' + results);
  Logger.log('results.items[0].id: ' + results.items[0].id);

  return results.items;
}
```